# paypal rest node sdk "This transaction is invalid"

Tags: rest, paypal, transactions, sdk

I'm merchants using it payment api.

I had completed the sandbox sample.

It was confirmed that payment in the sandbox account.

But suddenly it is not working. Program code is not changed.

`"error : This transaction is invalid.

Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."`

A "sandbox" is not working.

But it works if i switch to "live".

I have to test more than 20 days in the same way.

Suddenly, should not I do not know why. :(

See the following (approval_url)

```
{ id: 'PAY-3YF970037H573622HK7QOABY',
 intent: 'sale',
 state: 'created',
 payer: { payment_method: 'paypal' },
 transactions:
 [ { amount: [Object],
 description: 'This is the payment description.',
 custom: '1',
 item_list: [Object],
 related_resources: [] } ],
 create_time: '2016-09-20T07:06:46Z',

 links:

 [ { href: 'htt ps://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3YF970037H573622HK7QOABY',
 rel: 'self',
 method: 'GET' },

 { href: 'htt ps://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8W611604UP656490X',
 rel: 'approval_url',
 method: 'REDIRECT' },

 { href: 'htt ps://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3YF970037H573622HK7QOABY/execute',
 rel: 'execute',
 method: 'POST' } ],

 httpStatusCode: 201 }
```

"approval_url" is not the sandbox

'execute' and 'self' are the sandbox

Answer (score 0):

It has been changed point

Today error information has changed.

"error : This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."

The contents of approval_url is the same.

But it is forced to put a "sandbox" in approval_url.

paypal page(approval_url) is loaded.

This way did not work yesterday.

But it work today.

Answer (score 0):

I sent e-mail to paypal echnical support.

paypal came the answer :

"
Hi

Based from the full logs, it seems that the buyer account that you used for this case is hitting a risk issue in attempting to pay for the payment.

I suggest for you to clear cookies and cache and then retry again using other sandbox account.

Thanks
"

However, it is now working fine.
So the correct answer can not be tested.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is something wrong with "EC", I'm trying to follow de the REST API exmples and I get the same results...

Any one

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain any information to solve the problem, and actually it can't be called an answer, please use comments instead.